# How do I rescale tick marks on a polar plot?

Tags: plotting

I am working with an external "number-crunching" application that generates radiation patterns for antennas.  The data that I am working with is a function of spherical angles theta and phi and it produces numbers in the range of 0 through some maximum value.  I want to plot using PolarPlot to show a "scaled" tick mark where the scaling is the result of some function that I write to do the proper transformation.  So, here is an example [below, phi is controlled externally and sometimes via Manipulate[]).

```
PolarPlot[
  gdb[180/Pi (Abs[Pi/2 - theta]), phi], {theta, 0, Pi}, 
  PolarAxes -> True, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
  PolarGridLines -> Automatic, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  PolarAxesOrigin -> Automatic]
```

And, this is the resultant plot:

[image: PolarPlot]

Now, the `PolarAxesOrigin` option given `Automatic` generates the axes labeled from 20 thru the maximum of 80.  However, for this same plot, the only change I want (in this example) is to scale that axes tick mark labels as 0.0 for the 80 tick mark label and then the inner concentric circles would be -10, -20, -30, -40, and so on.  Thus, the labeling are all negative numbers with zero as the maximum range on the PolarAxesOrigin.

I have researched various posted questions here and experimented using scaling features, tick functions, and other things (merely guessing) to figure out how to achieve this and nothing works right.  I am hoping that I can provide some kind of function that can do a transformation from the plotted values to some scaled tick mark labels.  Changing the data itself to be negative does not work, the resultant plot is not correct.

Comment: Your code is not a working example because there is no definition go `gdb`. So anyone who might want to help can't reproduce your problem, which greatly reduces the chance that you get an answer.

Comment: Sorry about that but the gdb function is an Interpolation of about 4000 or so data points for angles theta 0 to 90 and phi 0 to 360.  So, not really a function that can be easily included.  But, the range of the function I mentioned  which of course varies over the domain variables.

Answer (score 3):

It's a shame  you did not include your own function, so I will have to use a made up one. I do not know how to change that detail before the plot is generated, but inspection of the plot's InputForm (try `plot // InputForm // SequenceForm`) shows the general format of those labels. This can be modified after the fact as follows, using a global replacement to generate the ticks you want:

```
plot = PolarPlot[
         25 theta, {theta, 0, Pi},
         PolarAxes -> True,
         PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic},
         PolarGridLines -> Automatic,
         PlotRangeClipping -> False,
         PolarAxesOrigin -> Automatic
       ];

plot /. Text[Style[value_Real, {}], opts__] :> Text[Style[value - 80, {}], opts]
```

[image: modified plot]

Above I restricted the pattern for replacement using `val_Real` to avoid causing the same change to the *angular* ticks, which otherwise would also become e.g. `30° - 80`. "30°" is represented internally as `Times[30, Degree]`; that expression has head `Times` to Mathematica's eyes, and is not a real number (i.e. something with head `Real`), so it can be distinguished from the radial ticks that are plain real numbers instead.

Comment: A bit of a hack, this should be supported through a Ticks option no?

Comment: @M.R. It sure should be (indeed that was my first attempt), but I was unable to make `Ticks` work here, hence the hack,

Comment: So, I did the same hack on my plot and it worked.  Now, I need to figure out how it worked.  I understand the rule substitution but I do not understand the reason it works.  For example, Text[Style[value_Real,{}],opts__] is a pattern match but I would not have been able to come up with that pattern myself.  I figure value_Real matches any real value but I have never seen that before "the value part".  Also, why the opts__ ?  Does this match any options to be used in the substitution (my guess).

Comment: I noted that in my version of Mathematica (should be the most recent) the function SequenceForm is obsolete and no longer exists.  It is to be replaced with Row or Text.  I am not sure how this SequenceForm adds to the description of the InputForm so not sure how Row or Text would be used as a substitute.

Comment: @K7PEH The output of `InputForm` is normally formatted as text and does not allow the usual context-aware selection (e.g. keep clicking with the mouse to expand selection in a syntax aware fashion). `SequenceForm` makes the output more easily editable. `Row` does not work as well for this; `Text` is an acceptable but inferior substitute.

Comment: OK, thanks for the description of SequenceForm.  I will experiment a bit today.  So, I also figured out the reason for value_Real pattern as it gives an identifier name to the matched item (real number).  I had never used that before.

Comment: @K7PEH Yes, that's correct. The reason we need that is to avoid making the same change to the angular ticks, which otherwise would also become e.g. `30 Degree - 80`. Since 30º is really represented internally as `Times[30, Degree]`, that expression has head `Times` to Mathematica's eyes, and is not a real number (i.e. something with head `Real`). I've added the same to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for some reason `Ticks` does not work with `PolarPlot`.
I would prefer a more straight forward solution because of the obvious side effect of the above hack.
Additionally its more versatile to produce ticks and other items.

```
pplot = PolarPlot[ 
    { Style[ 4, Thick, Gray ], 
      Style[ 2 Sin[3x] + 4, Blue, Thick ] }, { x, 0, 2\[Pi] }, 
PlotRangeClipping -> False,
PolarAxes -> { True, False },
PolarGridLines -> { Range[12] * 30 Degree, Range[10] },
PolarTicks -> { "Degrees", Automatic },
PolarAxesOrigin -> { 0, 10 },
Epilog -> Table[Table[ Text[ v-4, pos ], { v, Drop[Range[9],{4}] } ], 
    { pos, { {0,v}, {0,-v}, {v,0}, {-v,0} } } ]
];
```

[image]

The radial axis is swiched off and substituted in the `Epilog` part.

Answer (score 1):

[`PolarTicks >> Details:`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolarTicks.html)

- For each axis, the following tick mark options can be given:

[image]

So we can use

```
radialTicks = Thread[{Subdivide[0, 80, 8], 
   Style[-#, 16, Red] & /@ Reverse[Subdivide[0, 80, 8]], .01, Green}]

PolarPlot[20 (2 + Sin[3 t]), {t, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PolarAxes -> True, 
 PolarGridLines -> {Subdivide[##, 24] &, Range[##, 10] &}, 
 PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", radialTicks}, 
 PolarAxesOrigin -> {Pi/2, 80}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can use a ticks *function* that uses the automatic radial axis range to construct a list of labeled ticks:

```
radialTicksFunction = Thread[{Subdivide[##, 8], 
    Style[-#, 16, Red] & /@ Reverse[Subdivide[##, 8]], .01, Green}] &;

PolarPlot[20 (2 + Sin[3 t]), {t, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PolarAxes -> True, 
 PolarGridLines -> {Subdivide[##, 24] &, Range[##, 10] &}, 
 PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", radialTicksFunction}, 
 PolarAxesOrigin -> {Pi/2, 80}]
```

to get

[image]